# How to parse diffrent resolution m3u8 urls from m3u8 variable?

Tags: php, jquery, parsing, m3u8

I got the following m3u8 as php variable($returned_content). Now i want to replace **proxy-63.somesite.com** part of all m3u8 with **video2.de.secondsite.net** then create a hyperlink for each resolution and place all the hyperlinks in textarea.(for each resolution hyperlink i want to place the resolution of m3u8 in bracket after hyperlink title).

could any one tell me how i can achieve this task? Thanks in advance

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=836280,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.64001f",RESOLUTION=768x432
http://proxy-63.somesite.com/sec(42341234k32jlkjk234lkwerwlk32432)/video/600/500/12345678_mp4_h264_aac_hq_2.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=246440,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.42000d",RESOLUTION=320x180
http://proxy-63.somesite.com/sec(45432kjkhjkj4535lkj34543454lkj43)/video/600/500/12345678_mp4_h264_aac_ld_2.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=460560,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.42001e",RESOLUTION=512x288
http://proxy-63.somesite.com/sec(dfgghdfdgd987435392429324343241k)/video/600/500/12345678_mp4_h264_aac_2.m3u8
```

PHP

```
$returned_content = get_data(''.$m3u8Url);


/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

    $link_text .="<a href=\"../Player.php?&vidID=".$m3u8Url."&title=".$title_name."\">".$title_name."."(".".$resolution.".")"</a><br/>\n";
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do.  You want to just replace a string in the file?  Or, do you actually need to parse the file?  What have you tried?

Comment: the m3u8 file data is from get_data funcion. It holds the sample data.